# Windows universal Right to Left support

Tags: win-universal-app, right-to-left

It is necessary to make the support of Right to Left style (both text and layout-s). I understand that when you set parent `Grid`'s properties `FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"` in all child controls it inherited.
The question is - is there any default setting, which will shift all we need in app? Or should I set every parent greeds `FlowDirection` by some king of flag and set this flag as `FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"` if we, for example in in Arab countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to support any right to left language will need to have a right to left layout too. You don't need to change [FlowDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.flowdirection) property of all of the elements since it is inherited by child elements.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.flowdirection):

> An object inherits the FlowDirection value from its parent in the
>   object tree. Any element can override the value it gets from its
>   parent. If not specified, the default FlowDirection is LeftToRight

So usually you need to set the property once for root element/frame of the Window.

However, some elements like [FontIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279514?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242752) does not mirror automatically. FontIcon has a MirroredWhenRightToLeft property:

> You can set the MirroredWhenRightToLeft property to have the glyph
>   appear mirrored when the FlowDirection is RightToLeft. You typically
>   use this property when a FontIcon is used to display an icon as part
>   of a control template and the icon needs to be mirrored along with the
>   rest of the control

For Image, you need to flip the image by transforms.

**Edit:**

You can set the property in the Application class where you create the main frame/page:

```
// Part of the App.xaml.cs in default UWP project template:

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {

#if DEBUG
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
   this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
}
#endif

Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

// Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
// just ensure that the window is active
if (rootFrame == null) {
// Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
   rootFrame = new Frame();

   rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

   if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated) {
       //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
   }

   //**********************
   // Set flow direction
   // *********************
   if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft) {
      rootFrame.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
   }

   // Place the frame in the current Window
   Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

   }
   ...
   ...
```

If you don't want to use code behind (I think its OK to use it for this scenario), you can implement [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209903) (Not recommended):

```
public class RightToLeftConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)  {
                    if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft) {
           return FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
        }
        return FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use it in XAML:

```
<Page
    ...
    ...
    FlowDirection="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RightToLeftConverter}}">
```

Comment: You are right, thank you so much!  Would you tell me - if there any way to do  bind it on current culture in XAML only, not it code behind?